# Upload file to firebase storage with firebase function v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm struggling with this a bit. I'm trying to upload a file using a firebase function.
Here is my code

```
export const uploadFile = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const fileName = req.query.fileName+"";
  console.log("fileName: ", fileName);
  const fileRef = await admin.storage().bucket("gs://some-bucket.appspot.com")
   .upload(fileName, {destination: "testFile.jpg"});
  res.status(200).send(fileRef);
});
```

This is the log of the function:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/football-stadium-night-imaginary-modelled-260nw-1912601503.jpg'

I'm trying to upload a file that come's into the query/body with a firebase function

Comment: You can't upload to storage directly from a URL (what appears to be in `fileName`) using the provided SDK.  You have to first download the URL locally to a buffer or file, then upload the contents of that to storage.

Comment: Thank's Doug!! I didn't know that. Any chance you can give me a example to download the URL locally? I'm trying to do it, but for the moment unsuccesfully :(

Comment: There are quite a few examples of downloading a file in Node.js already: https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+download+file+from+url. If you're having trouble making that work for your specific case, I recommend opening a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).